# Dual circuit track lights not working with dimmer switch

Tags: electrical

My dual circuit track lighting will not work with dimmer switches but will work with single pole light switches. I purchased the correct dimmer switch to go with the LED bulbs I have. When connected to the dimmers one light works on both switches, none of the others do. Any ideas why? Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain “dual circuit” track lights? Do you have 2 separate track lights wired to 1 dimmer / switch?  2 switches 1 track light? Trouble shooting is much different. You should also take the tour so you will understand things like dimmer models or type and photos of the connections can help.

Comment: **Unlike normal 3-way switches**, the LED dimmers that will work as 3-way switches I've personally met (there may be others that behave differently) will **only** work on the switch position where the power from the panel (unswitched hot) is supplied to the circuit. But it's not clear if this relates to your actual problem... More details (and pictures) would be helpful.